Multidimensional arrays cannot be serialized from System.Text.Json
I wanted to serialize an object with a multidimensional array in it. Found out that its not a supported collection type by System.Text.Json.
Anyone know the reason behind it? Newtonsoft supports to the same operation.
In that case, is it performant if I write a custom jsonConverter to handle serializing 2D arrays? The object I get can have a large 2D array.
My ultimate goal is to save the object in a distributed cache using IDistributedCache. Happy to know if anyone has a better approach.
Thanks!

Anyone know the reason behind it? -- because, in the words of Eric Lippert, "Features are unimplemented by default; C# does not have that feature because no one designed, implemented and shipped the feature to customers.".  See e.g. JsonSerializer support for multi-dimensional arrays #44347 which was closed as not implemented.

For 2d arrays you can use Array2DConverter from this answer to How can I serialize a double[,] 2d array to JSON using System.Text.Json?.  In fact I think that's a duplicate, agree?
